# Find active element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm using banner rotator this one [Slide Box](http://manos.malihu.gr/slidebox-jquery-banner-rotator) when i need to find the active or currently visible banner's li id.

`$(this).attr('class');`

Something similar.

Comment: Can you please give us an example of what you have already tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current index from:

```
<div class="slideboxThumbs">
  <a href="#" class="slideboxThumb" rel="1"></a>
  <a href="#" class="slideboxThumb selectedSlideboxThumb" rel="2"></a>
  <a href="#" class="slideboxThumb" rel="3"></a>
</div>
```

In this example, we can see the second image is currently being shown.

```
$(".selectedSlideboxThumb").index(".slideboxThumbs a");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way is to get the position of the slide being clicked. In [the plain demo](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/slidebox/simple_slidebox/plain_demo.html) all the slides are 600px width. The main tag —  has the following propeties:

> width: 2400px;
>   left: 0px;
>   overflow: hidden;

So, when you click a slide, {left} property change to 600px. That's all.